# Algorithm to remove redundant parentheses from a boolean expression

Tags: infix-notation, reduction, prefix-operator

I have a boolean expression in prefix notation. Lets say it is `or and A B or or C D E`. When I convert it to infix notation I end up with
`((A and B) or ((C or D) or E))`. I want to reduce it to `(A and B) or C or D or E`. Should I reduce infix notation or is it actually easier to get reduced equation from prefix notation. What algorithms should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paranthesis can be removed in expression   `X % (X1 ? X2 ?  .. ? Xn) % X(n+1)` where Xi is a parenthesized expression or boolean value "?" and "%" are operators if and only if each "?" operator has precedence higher or equal to "%" operator.

For infix notation you would find innermost expression, check if parenthesis can be removed, save result, process parent expresion and continue until all parenthesis checks are done.

This turns into a mapping problem.  Postfix notation makes parenthesis elimination easy. Translation between prefix, infix and postfix notations is trivial.